# Scraping Issue while extracting data from the source

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape :- https://www.adsbhub.org/station.php?id=2018 using selenium and I am able to do so.

Is there any alternative for selenium in this case as we are not allowed to use selenium where I am working?

I tried using:-

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.adsbhub.org/station.php?SessID=&StationID=2018&webkey=f52c6b61bab2*80wwe952*d5a2*e2*8c968")
```

but getting an error:-

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 field in line 7, saw 4

I am new to the concept and have no idea about this error.

```
data = json.loads(r)
```

getting an error.

I need to scrape the table given in the URL. Can anyone suggest how to proceed on this.

Comment: Perhaps try [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) as an alternative.  The reason you are getting an error when you're using Pandas (pd) is because `pd.read_csv` expects the URL to link directly to a CSV, and the link you provided does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know how to use scrappy learning the same. Is there any other option that can be used for now?

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the `df` line to this:

```py
df= pd.read_csv('link', on_bad_lines='skip')
```

But this means that the lines that cause errors will be skipped, so if you need those lines this probably wont work for you.

Comment: thanks for the help, but this is not working here. It's just giving the html data in tabular format:-

 <!doctype html>
0 <html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
1 <head>
2 <title>ADS-B Station EDDN Stats - Nürnberg...
3 <meta charset="utf-8">
4 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content...
... ...
188 </div>